# Has anyone found an efficient way to store BSON ObjectId values in an SQL database?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, bson

We are migrating some data from MySQL to Mongo and have been adding extra fields to some of our DB tables for the [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype) value of the migrated data objects.

At the moment we are storing them as varchar(24) latin1_general_ci which works fine.

However, for efficient storage/indexing we probably should convert back to the 12-byte binary value. Unfortunately, MySQL only seems to have [native integer support up to 8 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html). Is there another option - binary perhaps?

**Update**: I am migrating from MySQL but only certain tables at the moment. So I first make duplicates of the objects in Mongo of a certain table. Then I go back to any other tables left in MySQL that have foreign key references to that old MySQL table ID and add a new reference field that will store the Mongo object's ID. I will then remove the original reference field the BIGINT.

**Update 2:** The reason I bring this up is that it may be 12 months more (or never) before we move this other data, so it will have a performance impact on the live web application until then.

Comment: Are you migrating **from** MySQL or **to** it?

Comment: thanks for sharing, I do the same, using same key struct(ObejctId) in MS Sql Server 2012, MongoDb, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range of a 12-byte unsigned int would be `0..79228162514264337593543950335` (29 digits max); according to docs (same URL you cited), a `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` column packs each group of nine base10 digits into four bytes (adding up to `floor(29 / 9) * 4 = 3 * 4 = 12` bytes for the first 27 digits), with the remaining 2 digits taking an additional byte, coming up to 13 bytes of storage for a `DECIMAL(29)` column.

Or, you can store them as `BINARY(12)`.

Comment: Looks like binary(12) might work nicely. I think the JDBC drivers might even be able to marshal the hex ObjectID automatically...

Comment: We have a software application with 1) Web-based component, 
2) Mobile-based component.  Our 1) Web-based component uses
a) MongoDB as the Database b) ASP.NET C#
Our 2) Mobile-based component uses a) Java b) SQL Lite
However, both the databases have the same tables, but we have Not created any sort of bridge table between the collections in MongoDB and the tables in the SQL Lite.  Do you believe your solution could work  in my case?

Comment: @CSLewis SQLite3 does not have a `decimal` type. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), I'd say you probably want to use the `BLOB` type (which seems close enough to MySQL's `BINARY` type) and store the object id as a binary value if you're really concerned about efficient storage, or as `TEXT` if you don't really care.

Comment: If you stored it as binary(12) would you be able to join on it still? What would be the effeciency of using a binary column as a primary / foreign key column?