# How to store mongo ObjectID into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb

We are transferring some data from MongoDB to SQL Server. To store mongo's objectid in SQL Server, I have a column of type `varbinary(12)`.

**Question #1**: is this a correct way to store mongo's objected in SQL Server?

Also when I convert objectid using

```
select CONVERT(varbinary(12),'54aedb94e6c12b1c0e83385f')
```

I get back `0x353461656462393465366331`

**Question #2**: in C#, how do I convert this stored binary back to string hexadecimal value?

**Question #3**: I am using EF with a database-first approach. How do I query the SQL Server table for the matching objectid (considering Objectid is stored as `varbinary`)

```
   public vod DoWork(string mongoid)
   {
        //how do i get client based on `mongoid` parameter which is string?
        var result = _dbContext.Clients.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.MongoId == ?????)
   }
```

assume that `MongoId` is varbinary column

Comment: Have you considered storing the ObjectID as just a string i.e. `'54aedb94e6c12b1c0e83385f'` ?

Comment: that's how I am storing it currently. but then I read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978807/has-anyone-found-an-efficient-way-to-store-bson-objectid-values-in-an-sql-databa

Answer (score 3):

as this proposition will lead to increase storage footprint, as an outcome we will have a possibility to create multi-field index.

solution:
add fields that will store extra info (Pid Timestamp Increment Pid)

```
var o = new ObjectId();
var o1 = o.Timestamp; //int
var o2 = o.Increment; //int
var o3 = o.Machine; //int
var o4 = o.Pid; //short
```

and for particular objsctId we could have:

```
objectID: 57ce88b4857eda2fe48f042f 
Timestamp: 1473153204 
Machine: 8748762 
Pid: 12260 
Increment: 9372719
```