# Transfer to the SQL Server database the same _id as the mongodb when I export object

Tags: sql-server, node.js, mongodb

I work with a mean stack: node, express, angular, mongodb.

The project with module to orders.

The customer selects a product, with specifications, adds to the card, give the order: choose among payment method, finalizing.

During `exports.createOrder = function (req, res)`, creating a record to the database mongo with its unique _id.

I need this data also save to a SQL Server database.

That's why at this point, I create additionally a connection to SQL Server  using `mssql` library and assigns variables `sql.Request() .input('Order_ID'), sql.NVarChar (255) order._id)` and others.

Call out at this point, the procedure .execute ('AddOrder'), located on the SQL Server which adds data to the table orders.

The problem is that `_id` saved object is different in the two databases. The other variables are the same.

At the time of updating the order in the SQL Server database creates a new row with `_id`, now the same as in mongo, but does not overwrite my old row -  logical because the update when finds orderID.

**All data record are saved. Except _id which is  overwritten.
In the mongo database for example I have: 586a8871a14d27e81a55533d but in mssql is 586a8871a14d27e81a55533f.
Mongo creates new _id. exactly it is changed 3-byte counter.**

I mean accurate data in both databases, but rather some data needs to save besides mongo to sql.
a secondary identifier in mssql not need / not used.

Is there a way to pass the same object `_id` to the SQL Server database, when you make order so as to mongo not created at the moment of the new `_id`?

And why, for example, if I set auto increment `_id`, at this point the `_id` column in SQL Server database ends up being `NULL`?

How to pass additional `new_id`, which is set to auto increment to the SQL Server database? Writes to mongo but in the whole project is UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo id and SQL id are different by default, usually in SQL default id is integer type. You need to create id in SQL which is string type (primary key called "id", type string) to be able to copy id from mongo to SQL.

It would be great for you to provide some code for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the Mongo ObjectID is binary, so converting it to a string just shows the textual representation of the binary. Instead of `sql.NVarChar (255)` can you use `sql.Binary (12)`? See this post from much smarter people: [Has anyone found an efficient way to store BSON ObjectId values in an SQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978807/has-anyone-found-an-efficient-way-to-store-bson-objectid-values-in-an-sql-databa)